# MySQL DEFAULT random string value

Tags: mysql, sql

3дpacтвyйтe, мне нужно поставить значение одной колонны как случайный набор букв и цифр. Я решил использовать `MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP())`.

Как можно поставить такое дефолтное значение колонны?

Я имею ввиду что по типу `CREATE TABLE test(test TEXT DEFAULT MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()));`

Я понимаю что применение функции MD5() в таком запросе выдаёт строчку, и выходит синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Какая ошибка? При выполнении какого оператора?

Comment: *Как можно поставить такое дефолтное значение колонны?* Никак. Значение по умолчанию обязано быть детерминированным. Исключение - автоприсваиваемое значение текущего штампа времени. Используйте BEFORE INSERT триггер.

Comment: Под MariaDB работает.
INSERT INTO test(test) values(default);

Дефолтное значение не обязательно должно быть детерминированным, например, current_timestamp не является детерминированным, но все его используют.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=baeef922f9ff19492323ce5d4b27be8e

Comment: Спасибо⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀